# Im making a quiz using windows forms and C# but it keeps displaying the same question

Tags: c#, arrays, list, winforms, random

It reads in questions/answers/topics etc from a .txt file and stores it in an array called ‘questionArray’ which is split by commas into another array called ‘splitDetails’. The if statement selects questions of a particular difficulty level and topic from the list and creates a new question ‘newQ’ of type MultipleChoice which has properties like QuestionText, Choice1, Choice2 etc. and its added to a list called ‘allQuestions’. populateTextboxes() picks a random question from the ‘allQuestions’ list and sets it to the object ‘currentQ’ which is of type MultipleChoice, then deletes it from the list so it isn’t shown again.

```
{
if (File.Exists("MultipleChoice questions.txt")) //checking file exists
{
   string[] questionArray = File.ReadAllLines("MultipleChoice questions.txt"); //create array of all questions 

   foreach (string Q in questionArray)
   {
        string[] splitDetails = Q.Split(',');  //create new array split by commas
if (splitDetails[6] == Quiz.DifficultyLevel && splitDetails[7] == Quiz.CurrentTopic)
       {
            newQ.QuestionText = splitDetails[0]; 
              newQ.Choice1 = splitDetails[1];
              newQ.Choice2 = splitDetails[2];
              newQ.Choice3 = splitDetails[3];
              newQ.Choice4 = splitDetails[4];
              newQ.Answer = splitDetails[5];
              newQ.Difficulty = splitDetails[6];
              newQ.Topic = splitDetails[7];
              newQ.QuestionType = splitDetails[8]; 

              allQuestions.Add(newQ); 

         }
      }
   }
   Else MessageBox.Show("No question file found", "File not found");
}

//add text to blank question form
public MultipleChoice populateTextboxes() 
{
  Random myNum = new Random();

  if (allQuestions.Count > 0)
  {
    questionCount += 1;

       //select random question from all questions
       int randomNumber = myNum.Next(0, allQuestions.Count);
       currentQ = allQuestions[randomNumber];
       allQuestions.Remove(currentQ);//remove used uestion so it isnt used again
  }

  //when the round is over (3 questions asked)
  if (questionCount == 4) 
  {
    //open keyboardQuestion
    this.Close();
    KeyboardInput k = new KeyboardInput();
    k.Show();

   }

   lblQuestion.Text = currentQ.QuestionText; 
   btnChoice1.Text = currentQ.Choice1;
   btnChoice2.Text = currentQ.Choice2;
   btnChoice3.Text = currentQ.Choice3;
   btnChoice4.Text = currentQ.Choice4;

   return currentQ;
}
```

Comment: I would set a breakpoint at the top of the `populateTextboxes()` method and step through it each time it executes. Should be easy to spot the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet it always displays the last question?

If newQ is globally declared, then that code is going to generate a bunch of different questions that are in fact all composed of a same object. The line allQuestions.add() will keep adding the same object to the collection. You can change one of the properties before or after adding it to collection and it will change in all the questions. Imagine 10 people reading the same newspapers article. What you want is 1 person reading 10 different articles, really.

Declare newQ locally, inside foreach() loop, and it will result in creating a new object with unique properties during each iteration.